# How to monitor SFTP with monit

Tags: debian, ftp, sftp, monit, proftpd

I just installed monit and checked the web interface. Unfortunately proftpd is marked as not running although it's running. I think it's because I'm running proftpd with S/FTP not FTP. 
Is it possible to run monit with S/FTP?

```
##CHECK ProFTPD
check process proftpd with pidfile /var/run/proftpd.pid
start program = "/etc/init.d/proftpd start"
stop program = "/etc/init.d/proftpd stop"
if failed port 21 protocol sftp then restart
if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
```

Comment: Show us your monit configuration file.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/nGgG5H0S

Answer (score 0):

Your ProFTPd check is looking at port 21. Sftp should probably be on port 22, and is already covered in the ssh check you have in place.

Remove the *"if failed port 21 protocol sftp then restart"*. It's unnecessary.

Comment: it might be ftp+ssl is what he meant

Comment: Possibly, but if `ftps` is being used, the Monit check is still incorrect.